# Are anti-limescale (anti-cal) shut-off valves just a marketing stunt?

Tags: plumbing, valve

I have found anti-lime (anti-cal) valves, they were ball valves with a plastic ball inside instead of the usual brass/chrome.

Is it a marketing trick or is the plastic ball inside better in any way then the commons for sink/tap water or washing appliances like washing machines or dishwashing machines.

If they really work, does clearing limescale really matter?

Comment: the chlorine in city water can oxidize the plastic and negate any advertised benefit of its antilimescale plastic versus chrome versus brass.  It would also depend on the type of plastic.  Not sure what you mean by "clearing limescale".

Answer (score 0):

Since most scale is a reaction between chemicals in water and a metal surface, using a plastic ball in theory will not allow the scale to build up on the ball. If you are using these valves on domestic water they would probably be a waste of time Unless your water is extremely hard or has an excessive amount of chemicals in it.

Comment: do they have any cons, like durability and such? I do have a very hard water.

Comment: Be sure to drain some water from hot water tank often.  Bottom of tank is main place sediment forms/collects.